# Permissions in .git so that apache (PHP web frontend) is allowed to commit

Tags: permissions, git

I have a git-based wiki system which has a PHP web front-end using a local Apache2 web server. From within PHP I run `git commit ...` which should be allowed to commit changes made to the wiki files. However, I have to pull and push using my default user because of the user identity (my private SSH key file). Which permissions should I use for the `.git` folder and its contents? If I use the default permissions, apache isn't allowed to lock the index and thus fails to commit the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than running shell commands from your PHP application, I suggest to start writing your web application to use Git programmatically using a PHP-Git binding library. For example [php-git](https://github.com/libgit2/php-git).

This has many advantages, such as not having to parse the command line output which may change in a future release of Git.

About the file system permissions, just log in on the server as which the PHP application server is running (i.e. `su -l www-data -s /bin/bash` on Debian-based systems) and create a public/private keypair for that user. Keep all file ownership to the web user for that clone of the repository.